# Why does this json parse with null attributes?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, pojo

I have the following code, JSON and POJO, however even though the JSON attributes have values, the resulting dataToUse object has null for name and date. Is there a special way to handle '@' in the json? I have another exactly similar piece of code which parses properly, but there is no '@'.

```
DataToUse dataToUse = new Gson().fromJson(json.toString(), DataToUse.class);
```

JSON:

```
{“@name”: “A Name”,“@date”: "2017-12-11T18:00:00-05:00"}
```

POJO:

```
public class DataToUse {
    private String name;
    private Date date;

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public Date getDate() { return this.date; }
    public void setDate(Date date) { this.date = date; }
}
```

Comment: There is @ icon before the attribute name, it would work fine if you delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below, by adding @SerializedName annotation

```
    public class DataToUse {
        @SerializedName("@name")
        private String name;
        @SerializedName("@date")
        private Date date;

        public String getName() { return this.name; }
        public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

        public Date getDate() { return this.date; }
        public void setDate(Date date) { this.date = date; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically with GSON you need to register a Date parsing capability in the create gson process. I usually make a wrapper class called JsonHelper to make my life easier. Notice the Date handling piece. But you are likely having issue with your @ symbol, but you may also need to handle the date formatting.

```
/**
 * Created by App Studio 35 on 3/18/15.
 */
public class JSONHelper {

    /*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // MEMBERS
    *///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private static Gson mGson; //Google's JSON to Object Converter
    private static final String TAG = JSONHelper.class.getSimpleName();


    /*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // PROPERTIES
    *///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    protected static Gson getGson(){
        return mGson == null ? mGson = getGsonBuilder().create() : mGson;
    }


    /*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // METHODS
    *///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private static GsonBuilder getGsonBuilder(){
        //Used for Building a Gson Converter a Google Product for JSON Translation to Objects
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        //Created as Static so Fragments can easily use the same Builder.
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {

            @Override
            public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

                //Specify the way we format Dates in this Converter
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault());
                format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                String date = json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString();

                try {
                    return format.parse(date);

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "getGsonBuilder failed to register Date: " + e.getMessage());
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);

                }
            }
        });
        return builder;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param objectToConvert to convert to Json
     * @param classType the class that we are serializing from into a String
     * @return
     */
    public static String toJson(Object objectToConvert, Class classType){
        try {
            String msg = "";
            //Get String from Gson converter for Class Type
            msg = getGson().toJson(objectToConvert, classType);

            //Return String of Json from passed in Object
            return msg;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() == null ? "null" : e.getMessage());
            return "";

        }
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param objectToConvert to convert to Json
     * @param classType the Type that we are serializing from into a String
     * @return
     */
    public static String toJson(Object objectToConvert, Type classType){
        try {
            String msg = "";
            //Get String from Gson converter for Class Type
            msg = getGson().toJson(objectToConvert, classType);

            //Return String of Json from passed in Object
            return msg;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() == null ? "null" : e.getMessage());
            return "";

        }
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param objectToConvert Object to convert to JSON string
     * @return json string to represent the passed object
     */
    public static String toJson(Object objectToConvert){
        try {
            String msg = "";
            //Get String from Gson converter for Class Type
            msg = getGson().toJson(objectToConvert);

            //Return String of Json from passed in Object
            return msg;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() == null ? "null" : e.getMessage());
            return "";

        }
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param json String to convert into Object for the class that was passed
     * @param classType the class that we are serializing from
     * @return
     */
    public static Object fromJson(String json, Class classType){
        try {
            //Get Object from Gson converter of Json
            Object obj = getGson().fromJson(json, classType);

            //Return filled in object of passed in Class Type
            return obj;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() == null ? "null" : e.getMessage());
            return null;

        }
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param json String to convert into Json for the class that was passed
     * @param classType the Type that we are serializing from
     * @return
     */
    public static Object fromJson(String json, Type classType){
        try {
            //Get Object from Gson converter of Json
            Object obj = getGson().fromJson(json, classType);

            //Return filled in object of passed in Class Type
            return obj;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() == null ? "null" : e.getMessage());
            return null;

        }
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param jsonElement JsonElement to convert into Object for the class that was passed
     * @param classType the class that we are serializing from
     * @return
     */
    public static Object fromJson(JsonElement jsonElement, Class classType){
        try {
            //Get Object from Gson converter of Json
            Object obj = getGson().fromJson(jsonElement, classType);

            //Return filled in object of passed in Class Type
            return obj;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() == null ? "null" : e.getMessage());
            return null;

        }
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param jsonElement String to convert into Object for the class that was passed
     * @param classType the class that we are serializing from
     * @return
     */
    public static Object fromJson(JsonElement jsonElement, Type classType){
        try {
            //Get Object from Gson converter of Json
            Object obj = getGson().fromJson(jsonElement, classType);

            //Return filled in object of passed in Class Type
            return obj;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() == null ? "null" : e.getMessage());
            return null;

        }
    }
    public static Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, Object> retMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if(json != JSONObject.NULL) {
            retMap = toMap(json);
        }
        return retMap;
    }
    public static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Iterator<String> keysItr = object.keys();
        while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
            String key = keysItr.next();
            Object value = object.get(key);

            if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            }

            else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return map;
    }
    public static List<Object> toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            Object value = array.get(i);
            if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            }

            else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            list.add(value);
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems like a lot of code for what is being asked

Comment: @cricket_007 it is a helper class to register his date management. Sometimes it is nice to have a copy and paste solution from help instead of snippets that you have to piece together. I like to be thorough. The main part he would care about is the getGsonBuilder as this is the part most GSON users typically skip as they don't understand it or use it enough to recognize it's purpose.

Comment: I am a 'she' :)
The date did parse just fine without anything extra. I knew that would work since I have another call that returns json without '@' symbols and everything there parsed without issue. In this case it really was just the '@' symbol that required extra attention.

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the `@` from the parameters

```
{“@name”: “A Name”,“@date”: "2017-12-11T18:00:00-05:00"}


{“name”: “A Name”,“date”: "2017-12-11T18:00:00-05:00"}
```

Try this solution.

Comment: This assumes the JSON source is editable. If it comes from an external API, this is unlikely

Comment: Technically I could have done this on the client side by first grabbing the JSONObject, converting it to a string, then removing all '@' before using gson.fromJson. Although I prefer the answer I chose above, this would have worked as well.